# How do I convert two specific columns in data frame to a numpy array?

Tags: python, data-science

I'm trying to convert the specific values within its two columns: 'unemployed' and 'low_wage_jobs', in my data frame: recent_grads.

I tried the following code:

```
recent_grads_np = recent_grads[['unemployed','low_wage_jobs']].to_numpy()
```

but then I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    recent_grads_np = recent_grads[['unemployed','low_wage_jobs']].to_numpy()
  File "<stdin>", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    recent_grads_np = recent_grads[['unemployed','low_wage_jobs']].to_numpy()
  File "script.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
```

why is it? and what should I write?

Comment: try `.values` instead of `.to_numpy()`. It was deprecated in version 0.24, but it seems your pandas version is older, as it doesn't have `to_numpy`